# Protecting assets in BLOB storage using Azure B2C

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web app (asp.net core) which authenticates using Azure B2C for user accounts (OIDC). I now want to allow the users to access ‘protected resources’ such as images etc. My plan is to put these in Azure blob storage but I need to protect these so that only the authorized user can access their own image. I don’t want the scenario where anyone who knows the URL of a file can access it, only the logged in user.
Is this possible with Azure B2C and Blob storage, and if so, what is the best approach to secure these?

I was thinking of creating a container per user, with their B2C Object ID as the container name, so the structure may look like:

```
Files/04aaffcc-c725-4ff5-9565-cc2fb3d7b4df/image1.jpg
Files/04aaffcc-c725-4ff5-9565-cc2fb3d7b4df/image2.jpg
Files/04aaffcc-c725-4ff5-9565-cc2fb3d7b4df/movie1.mp4
Files/81f052a1-c8c2-4db5-9872-c16c803d1c3f/image66.jpg
Files/81f052a1-c8c2-4db5-9872-c16c803d1c3f/movie-19.mp4
```

So I need to restrict access so that only the logged in user with the correct object id (e.g. 81f052a1-c8c2-4db5-9872-c16c803d1c3f) can access their own resources (e.g. image66.jpg)

Any ideas on how best to implement this and what constructs Azure supports?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that users can't access the blob storage files directly. The storage should be abstracted by your service since storage and implementation can change anytime.

I would also have another folder (named images) inside objectId container because there might be different types of file in future.

Then lets say service is hosted on http://contoso.com. The image url to the user provided will be http://contoso.com/userImages/image123.jpg

When someone tries to access the resource, I would read objectId from the token and grant access accordingly.

You should think of sharing scenarios as well, you will need to build another table for the same as who owns the resource and who is it shared with. ObjectId based containers are not useful in such cases, it might be a flat container with image names as guid. and then mapping image names to the file name and other properties.

Answer (score -1):

Usa Shared Access Signatures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview.